# Is it possible to develop an offline map application with directions in a PWA App?

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, progressive-web-apps, mapbox-gl-js

I am looking into the possible ways available to create an offline map(download a city or country) with direction feature (example: point A to Point B). because of the offline criteria, I am looking into PWA application methodology as it can store cached data in the browser.

Are there any .js library that can help me achieve this.
references I have came across so far:

MapBox:
https://www.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/web-apps/#how-web-apps-work

Leaflet.js:
https://leafletjs.com/

any suggestions or tips on this? Thank you in Advance.

Comment: It's unlikely there is a pure JS solution that will do this. Routing is hard. You can look at the native app OsmAnd to get a sense of the problem you're dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vast majority of routing / direction features use an online service for the routing part, PWA or not.

The offline map part is not easy but much more doable, very probably more as a native or hybrid mobile app rather than a PWA with limited storage.